# NSWindow keep in back of all windows/apps

Tags: macos, osx-lion, nswindow

So not really sure how to even google search this question... But, I'd like to make an NSWindow, reside in the back of all other windows/apps & I want it to be displayed on every Mission Control space (still in the back).

I've seen other applications that do this, so I know it's possible, just don't know how.

(I'm referring to Lion's function called Mission Control where you can switch through different spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, there's a method/enum to make it so that the window will appear in all "spaces" (mission control).

`[self.window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];`

And a method to keep the window to the farthest back possible.

`[self.window setLevel:kCGDesktopIconWindowLevelKey - 1];`

All you have to do is use these two methods, and it'll do exactly what I requested. However, I wish there was a way to keep it from animating when coming down from Mission control (there is non to my knowledge).

Comment: I don't think `NSWindowBelow` is what you want. The `NSWindowOrderingMode` constants express relative ordering rather than absolute ordering, and are intended for use with `orderWindow:relativeTo:` and friends. See my answer for pointers to the correct set of constants, and for information on how to address your unresolved Mission Control issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the NSWindow's `level` and `collectionBehavior` properties.

The window level you'll want to use will depend on what behavior you're after from your window. You can find constants for the available window levels in CoreGraphics/CGWindowLevel.h. I'd suggest trying `CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDesktopIconWindowLevelKey) ± 1`.

Which collection behavior you specify will also depend on what behavior you're after. The brief description in your question suggests that `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces` may be a good starting point.